# Change from pip 3.4 to 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pip

Recently, I have installed python3.5 on Raspberry Pi 3, while I had 3.4 (by default). So now I have a problem with pip, because it is linked with 3.4 and not 3.5, so whenever I install package, it is done for 3.4 and not 3.5. I have no clue how to fix it. This is what I tried:

```
pip -V
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
pip3 -V
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)
```

Anything like pip-3.4/5 does not work

From: https://docs.python.org/3.5/installing/index.html

```
python3.5 -m pip install <package_name>
/usr/local/bin/python3.5: No module named pip
```

But same approach works for python2.7 and 3.4.

Last attempted was with:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

Got an error:

```
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1558k  100 1558k    0     0  1880k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1879k
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pip
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
```

Comment: Run `python3.5 -m ensurepip`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Some distributions have [omitted ensurepip from their Python installations](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847) for reasons which are entirely too tiresome to go into (TL;DR: "No, package management is *my* job!").  So far as I can tell, they stopped doing that, but it is regrettably not safe to assume that ensurepip exists on all systems.

Comment: I have found it extremely helpful to use `pyenv`, also it might be the case that when you installed python3.5 the ssl libraries were not installed, basically when the python library compiles, if the SSL dependencies are not installed, the python `ssl` module is not compiled and thus will not be able to make https requests try `apt-get install libssl-dev` and try to reinstall python3.5, then `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.5` then `python3.5 -m pip --version` OR try `curl http://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.5` notice no `https`